# Open two text files, process them and write to separate files

Tags: perl, file, output

I'm using with Perl to open two text files, process them and then write the output to another file.

I have a file `INPUT` were every line is a customer. I will process each line into variables that will be used to substitute text in another file, `TEMP`. The result should be written into individual files for each customer, `OUTPUT`.

My program seems to be working on only the first file. The rest of the files remain empty with no output.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

if ( $#ARGV < 0) {
    print "Usage: proj5.pl <mm/dd/yyyy>\n";
    exit;
}

my $date = $ARGV[0];

open(INFO, "p5Customer.txt") or die("Could not open p5Customer.txt file\n");
open(TEMP, "template.txt")   or die("Could not open template.txt file\n");

my $directory = "Emails";
mkdir $directory unless(-e $directory);

foreach $info (<INFO>){

    ($email, $fullname, $title, $payed, $owed) = split /,/, $info;
    next if($owed < $payed);
    chomp($owed);

    $filepath = "$directory/$email";
    unless(open OUTPUT, '>>'.$filepath){
        die "Unable to create '$filepath'\n";
    }

    foreach $detail (<TEMP>){
        $detail =~ s/EMAIL/$email/g;
        $detail =~ s/(NAME|FULLNAME)/$fullname/g;
        $detail =~ s/TITLE/$title/g;
        $detail =~ s/AMOUNT/$owed/g;
        $detail =~ s{DATE}{$date}g;
        print OUTPUT $detail;
    }

    close(OUTPUT);
}

close(INFO);
close(TEMP);
```

Comment: always `use strict` unless you have a _very_ good reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been said, you need to open your template file again each time you read from it. There's a bunch of other issues with your code too

- *Always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` and declare every variable with `my` as close as possible to where it is first used
- `$#ARGV` is the index of the last element of `@ARGV`, so `$#ARGV < 0` is much better written as `@ARGV < 1`
- You should use *lexical* file handles, and the three-parameter form of `open`, so `open(INFO, "p5Customer.txt")` should be `open my $info_fh, '<', "p5Customer.txt"`
- You should use `while` instead of `for` to read from a file
- It is easier to use the default variable `$_` for short loops
- It is pointless to capture a substring in a regular expression if you're not going to use it, so `(NAME|FULLNAME)` should be `NAME|FULLNAME`
- There is no point in closing input files before the end of your program

It is also much better to use an existing template system, such as
[`Template::Toolkit`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Toolkit)

This should work for you

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

if ( @ARGV < 1 ) {
    print "Usage: proj5.pl <mm/dd/yyyy>\n";
    exit;
}

my $date = $ARGV[0];

open my $info_fh, '<', 'p5Customer.txt' or die qq{Could not open "p5Customer.txt" file: $!};

my $directory = "Emails";
mkdir $directory unless -e $directory;

while ( <$info_fh> ) {

    chomp;
    my ($email, $fullname, $title, $payed, $owed) = split /,/;
    next if $owed < $payed;

    open my $template_fh, '<', 'template.txt' or die qq{Could not open "template.txt" file: $!};

    my $filepath = "$directory/$email";
    open my $out_fh, '>', $filepath or die qq{Unable to create "$filepath": $!};

    while ( <$template_fh> ) {

        s/EMAIL/$email/g;
        s/FULLNAME|NAME/$fullname/g;
        s/TITLE/$title/g;
        s/AMOUNT/$owed/g;
        s/DATE/$date/g;

        print $out_fh $_;
    }

    close($out_fh);
}
```

Comment: wow this solved it. This is my first Perl program, I knew I probably had some problems with my code, thanks for pointing them out and for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the TEMP loop is **inside** the INPUT loop and so the TEMP loop will end while the INPUT loop is still on the first line of the INPUT file.

Best to store TEMP file data into a hash table and work on the TEMP hash table inside the INPUT loop.

Good luck.

Comment: alternatively, open and close `TEMP` inside the `INFO` loop.

Comment: alternatively, `seek TEMP, 0, 0` before reading from it each time

Comment: I honestly don't like the open/close TEMP inside INFO loop as this would create a lot of unnecessary processing (file access versus hash table). If INFO file contains thousands of lines, the code would open/close TEMP thousands of times.

Comment: Borodin, your method would solve the OP's issue but it is still **reading** from TEMP file (file I/O is really not as optimal as hash table which is in memory). Anyway, JMHO.